# Android Extend MainActivity

Tags: java, android

I have a MainActivity class which has some menu code that other classes inherit by extending MainActivity on each class, my question is, if I have a toast message (as an example) on the onCreate of MainActivity and in one of my other classes (eg: Act_02) I extend MainActivity but do not want the toast (from MainActivity) to execute on Act_02 (which extends MainActivity) how can I achieve this without removing the extends MainActivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change the order of `onCreate` method in child activities do the below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);// I always want this in first line of onCreate
       showToast("Hello World!!");
    }

    public void showToast(String message){
       Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Activity2 which extends MainActivity

```
public class Activity2 extends MainActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // showToastMessage = false; // want to avoid here
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);// I always want this in first line of onCreate
    }

    public void showToast(String message) {
       // do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i used @Juan way of using a boolean but this code of yours "// showToastMessage = false; // want to avoid here" saved me as it needs to be directly under onCreate

Comment: @user3560827 True, by default in practice we always call **super.onCreate** as a first line, so we should avoid such dependencies. Thanks for sharing your views.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the code of `MainActivity`, you could add a protected boolean attribute `showToastMessage` and set it as true (which would be the default).

```
proteted boolean showToastMessage = true;
```

Then, in onCreate() you wrap the toast line inside an if:

```
if(showToastMessage){
    <put the toast line here>
}
```

In the class you don't want the toast to be shown, you set `showToastMessage` as false in the constructor.

```
public MyNewClass extends MainActivity{
    showToastMessage = false;
}
```

Other classes extending MainActivity will have the flag defaulted to `true`.

And all classes can call `super.onCreate()` for any super initialization to occur as expected.

Answer (score 0):

consider adding some `BaseActivity` and let `MainActivity` and others extend on that.

while you could just implement method `onCreate()` without called to `super.onCreate()`

... where `super` always refers to the class, which is being extended.

Answer (score 0):

You can place your code displaying the toast inside a function of `MainActivity` and override this function in `Act_02`.

```
public class MainActivity {

  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    displayInformation();
  }

  public void displayInformation() {
    // your Toast
    Toast.makeText(...);
  }
}

public class Act_02 extends MainActivity {

  @Override
  public void displayInformation() {
    // display something else
  }
}
```

Comment: in theory, yes - in practice, rather no... because extending the `MainActivity` sounds alike intentionally creating a mess; because it might have more or less specific code, while the basic intention might be to share common methods.